# CRM Plugin for Export to Excel

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I wish to write a plugin which intercepts export to excel function in dynamics CRM 4.0. I want to limit the data (based on a security logic) when user exports to excel contact data. 
I can not find a message related to export, it is just execute message. Is there any property in Exceutioncontext which could be used to identify export?

Comment: I'm shooting from the hip here...

I'm pretty sure the system is just pulling data with FetchXml and then it uses that to create the excel file.  In the execution context you can access the InputParameters and take out the value with key "FetchXml".  

That said I don't think anything will identify that an export is occurring, there is no message for that as far as I've seen.

Comment: Let me guess: "We need to make sure that people can't export our entire database of Accounts and Contacts!  M Farhan, can you do this?".  Am I close?

Comment: Not exactly. We need to put limit based on a security logic on what data is exported. This just need to happen for exporting. Other views, etc, might still expose same data. But when doing export to excel, the data returned (by default) should be limited to a set (based on a relationship logic).

Comment: Benjynito, you are right. I can not find with FetchXML (or any PluginContext property) any identification which could lead me to know if this an export. If you do an advanced find, and export the result, fetchXML is same in inputparameter.

Answer (score 1):

CRM 4.0 doesn't have a restriction on number of records can be exported. However, I've implemented using a custom ISV button, .Net Export page (similar to the one in OOB) and restricted the number of records based on the role (the role detail were maintained in the configuration). This is complete custom solution. The OOB export was disabled to the security roles.